# if Attribute VALUE already exists, remove it, otherwise add it jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to find a way in jQuery to check an attribute VALUE, and if that value *includes* something, remove it, otherwise add it.

So for example:

```
<body data-holidays="10 May 2021, 14 May 2021, 24 May 2021">

//If data-holidays INCLUDES 14 May 2021
if ( $('body').attr('data-holidays') == "14 May 2021" ) {
   //Delete "14 May 2021" from date-holidays but keep the rest

   //Changes it to: "<body data-holidays="10 May 2021, 24 May 2021">"
}
else {
  //ADD "10 May 2021" TO the end of date-holidays
   $('body').attr("data-holidays", function() { return $('body').attr("data-holidays") + ', 14 May 2021'  });
}
```

Comment: could you validate one of answers to close the question?

Answer (score 2):

using a regex expression does the job:

```
const dateselected = "14 May 2021";
const regex = new RegExp(dateselected + "[, ]*");
let sel = $('body').attr('data-holidays');
if ( sel.includes(dateselected)) {
   sel = sel.replace(regex,"");
   $('body').attr('data-holidays', sel)
}
else {
  //ADD "10 May 2021" TO the end of date-holidays
   $('body').attr("data-holidays", function() { return $('body').attr("data-holidays") + ', 14 May 2021'  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr(attributeName, function)` and split the string to array, check if the wanted one exists and  push it to array if needed, or filter it out , then return the joined string

```js
function updateHolidays($el, date){

    $el.attr('data-holidays',(i, curr)=>{
        let arr = curr.split(',').map(v => v.trim());
        if(arr.includes(date)){
           // is included so remove it
           arr = arr.filter(v=> v !== date)
        }else{
            // not included so add it
            arr.push(date)
        }
        return arr.join(', ')
    });
}

// should add one and remove one
const dates = ['14 May 2021','1 Oct 2021'];

const $el = $('[data-holidays]');
// modify multiple dates for demo
dates.forEach(d => updateHolidays($el, d));
//display results
console.log($el.attr('data-holidays'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-holidays="10 May 2021, 14 May 2021">

</div>
```